# How to make ssh connection in workflow through groovy script by using sand box in Jenkins?

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-cli, groovyshell, jenkins-workflow

How to make ssh connection in workflow through groovy script by using sand box in Jenkins?
we need to make a ssh connection to a server and run particular script on that server with a particular user id..

is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar requirement for our build system, and I started with [this ssh.gradle task](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tapestry/tapestry5/trunk/ssh.gradle).

It comes down to using ant's sshexec as follows:

```
class SshTask extends DefaultTask {

    // various properties for the host etc
    @Input @Optional String host
    @Input @Optional String userName
    @Input @Optional String password
    @Input @Optional String keyfile
    @Input @Optional String passphrase

    private static boolean antInited = false

    SshTask() {
        if (!antInited) {
            antInited = true
            initAnt()
        }
    }

    protected initAnt() {
        project.configurations { sshAntTask }
        project.dependencies {
            sshAntTask "org.apache.ant:ant-jsch:1.8.2"
        }
        ant.taskdef(name: 'sshexec',
                classname: 'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHExec',
                classpath: project.configurations.sshAntTask.asPath, loaderref: 'ssh')
    }

    def ssh(Object... commandLine) {
        def outputAntProperty = "sshoutput-" + System.currentTimeMillis()
        if (keyfile != null) {
            ant.sshexec(host: host, username: userName, keyfile: keyfile, passphrase: passphrase, command: commandLine.join(' '), outputproperty: "$outputAntProperty")
        } else if (password != null) {
            ant.sshexec(host: host, username: userName, password: password, command: commandLine.join(' '), outputproperty: "$outputAntProperty")
        } else {
            throw new GradleException("One of password or keyfile must be set to perform ssh command")
        }
        def sshoutput = ant.project.properties."$outputAntProperty"
        project.logger.lifecycle sshoutput
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no trick.

`sh 'ssh -u someone server some-script'`

Comment: Question asks for invoker be groovy, not sh.